# Filling list with Json data and getting the objects from it

Tags: c#, json, parsing, json.net, deserialization

I have a php webservice which gets the data from database and returns it as json data.

**Json data**

```
{"faqs":
   [
        {"faq":{"id":"123"}},
        {"faq":{"id":"124"}}
   ]
}
```

**Object classes**

```
public class FaqList
{
    public List<Faq> faqs { get; set; }
}
public class Faq
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

**Test class**

```
var client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("http://www.mydomain.com/webservice/7/server.php"));
var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

FaqList list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FaqList>(jsonString);

list.faqs.Count() => 2
list.faqs[0].id   => NULL !!
```

I fill all the objects to the 'list'. With count test I see that it's filled. But if I try to get an objects from it, I get null error.

So, how can I correctly fill my list so that I can get the objects from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://json2csharp.com/ suggests these definitions. (One more class `Faq2`)

```
public class Faq2
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Faq
{
    public Faq2 faq { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Faq> faqs { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this useful website. I've only edited my _object clasess_. The rest stays as it was. Then I can get the objects like `list.faqs[0].faq.id` .